# Get IP-address by URL

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

This works

```
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

but I want to put the IP from a website URL

I have tried

```
const char host[] = "http://www.google.com/";
struct hostent *host_ip;
host_ip = gethostbyaddr(host, strlen(host), 0);
```

I of corse did WSAStartup before I used gethostbyaddr();

I've tried this

```
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_ip);
```

I've tried a few simmilar ones too but it isn't working.
Could someone show me how to do this correctly.

Thank you!

EDIT:

When I do

```
host_ip = gethostbyaddr((char *)&host, strlen(host), 0);
std::cout << host_ip->h_addr;
```

It gives me

```
httpa104-116-116-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
```

Comment: Reduce your full code to a [MCVE], and post it in your question please. As is it's useless and off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I googled "nslookup source code", and was sent to (http://opensource.apple.com/source/bind9/bind9-44/bind9/bin/dig/nslookup.c). Possibly other source are better, I don't know. Google is your friend here. ;-)

Comment: here is the full code if you want to see it
http://pastebin.com/H4kvbfpy

Comment: There are _lots_ of resources online for this. "Of course" you already tried them, "but it isn't working". No point repeating them here then.

Comment: When I do

 host_ip = gethostbyaddr((char *)&host, strlen(host), 0);
 std::cout << host_ip->h_addr;

It gives me

 httpa104-116-116-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com

Comment: I question if you've thought about the function you're trying to use: gethostbyaddr "Get Host By Address". So, get a Host by its Address. Do you have an Address to start with? Because I don't see one.

Comment: const char host[] = "http://www.google.com/";
that's the address i was using

Comment: @KristijanKnežević That's not an address.  That's a hostname.

Answer (score 5):

`inet_addr()` accepts an IPv4 address string as input and returns the binary representation of that address.  That is not what you want in this situation, since you don't have a IP address, you have a hostname instead.

You are on the right track by using `gethostby...()`, but you need to use `gethostbyname()` (lookup by hostname) instead of `gethostbyaddr()` (lookup by IP address) <sup>1</sup>.  And you cannot pass a full URL to either of them.  `gethostbyname()` takes only a hostname as input, so you need to parse the URL and extract its hostname, and then you can do something like this:

```
const char host[] = ...; // an IP address or a hostname, like "www.google.com" by itself
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
if (target.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
{
    struct hostent *phost = gethostbyname(host);
    if ((phost) && (phost->h_addrtype == AF_INET))
        target.sin_addr = *(in_addr*)(phost->h_addr);
    ...
}
else
    ...
```

<sup>1</sup> BTW, the `gethostby...`() functions are deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` instead.

```
const char host[] = ...; // an IP address or a hostname, like "www.google.com" by itself

addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addrinfo *addr = NULL;

int ret = getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &addr);
if (ret == EAI_NONAME) // not an IP, retry as a hostname
{
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    ret = getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &addr);
}
if (ret == 0)
{
    target = *(sockaddr_in*)(addr->ai_addr);
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
    ...
}
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getaddrinfo. There's a quick guide to using it here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html