# How to get the IPv4-address of a URL

Tags: c, url, ipv4

I'm trying to get the ipv4 of a given URL for sending http requests trough socket, so far I've tried with `inet_pton` but it always return 0, does anyone has a suggestion for doing this?

Of course I'm trying to convert only the domain and not the entire URL (ex. URL: `http://agraria.org/`, domain: `agraria.org`).

**SOLUTION:**
http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/various/getaddrinfo.c.xp

Comment: `inet_pton` only converts from a printable IP-number to the binary equivalent. You need e.g. `getaddrinfo` to resolve the domain name into an address (which might include a DNS lookup).

Comment: I guess this Question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856963/2805824.